# How do i install app for android built using Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm new to mobile development, so please excuse me for silly questions.

Which files are needed in order to install the app ? the .apk file only ? i see a lot of files in the bin directory, and how do i even install the app ? do i just plug the smartphone into my PC, transfer the apk to the device and do what ?

And where can i get the Waze SDK ? I want to develop an app based on Waze, would appreciate an explanation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just need the **.apk file** in \bin\Debug.

Then connect your device to your PC (using **USB**) and transfer the .apk file into it.

After all, open the Explorer in your device and open the apk file.

Install it and it's done !

Comment: Alright, thanks man, and can you answer my 2nd question about the Waze SDK ?

Comment: Explained there : https://www.waze.com/fr/about/dev you need to adapt it for Xamarin (C# - Crossplatform)